# RAILS: One single controller in the "/" site-root taking variable requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

being quite new to the rails framework i dont know exactly where i missed the spot.

i want to do the following:

1. someone sends a rest request (get,put,post,delete) in the form of /var1/var2/var3.var4
2. i want to catch all 4 vars
3. nothing else will run on this app. i do not need views, etc.
4. my rails app responds with an appropriate response object

right now i don't get around the routes.rb part. i got this so far:

```
scope "/" do
   post ":var1/:var2[/:var3[.:var4]]" => "rest_proxy#post"
   get ":var1/:var2[/:var3[.:var4]]" => "rest_proxy#get"
   put ":var1/:var2[/:var3[.:var4]]" => "rest_proxy#put"
   delete ":var1/:var2[/:var3[.:var4]]" => "rest_proxy#delete"
end
```

my controller rest_proxy exists, the methods exist, but i get a "no route" error, no matter what i do so there must be something fundamentally wrong.

rake route shows the quivalent of what you see above.

if anyone could point me into the right direction that would be awesome (also about the response object, but that shouldn't be a big deal, right...?)...

thanks and regards,
anton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your `routes.rb`

```
post ":var1/:var2(/:var3(/:var4))" => "rest_proxy#post"
put ":var1/:var2(/:var3(/:var4))" => "rest_proxy#put "
get ":var1/:var2(/:var3(/:var4))" => "rest_proxy#get"
delete ":var1/:var2(/:var3(/:var4))" => "rest_proxy#delete"
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick answer! turns out i just was absolutely oblivious to what i was doing there. i had a cup of rtfm and now it's all good. 

just had to add a slash in the front and the whole scope thing was completely unneccessary.

i will now sit in the corner and learn this thing proper.

Comment: A cup of RTFM usually does wonders ;-). Although I usually put it in, the leading slash is optional (FYI). Here's an excellent guide if you're still in RTFM mode: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html